# Activity crashes when minimized and a dialog is opened

Tags: android, serialization, dialog, rotation, minimize

On my activity a show a Custom DialogFragement. But when I minimize the app while the dialog is opened i get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = xxx.xxx.MyActivity$24)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1468)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416)
at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:144)
at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1254)
at ....
... 23 more
java.io.NotSerializableException: xxx.xxx.MyActivity
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
xxxxx
```

For the moment to fix this I have set this in the dialog fragment which seems to works but I don't like these kind of of dirty tricks

```
@Override
  public void onPause() {
    dismiss(); 
    super.onPause();
  }
```

Anyone can tell me what causes this exception in the first place ?

The onCreate of the custom DialogFragment:

```
public static MyCustomDialog newInstance(double lat, double lng, MyListener listener) {
    MyCustomDialog dialogFragment = new MyCustomDialog();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble(ARG_LAT, lat);
    bundle.putDouble(ARG_LNG, lng);
    bundle.putSerializable(ARG_LISTENER, listener);
    dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return dialogFragment;
  }

@Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null, false);
    final double lat = getArguments().getDouble(ARG_LAT);
    final double lng = getArguments().getDouble(ARG_LNG);
    listener = (MyListener) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_LISTENER);
    TextView saveBtn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          /* some processing */
          listener.onSave();
          }
     });
 return view;
}
```

MyListener is an interface. I thought at first that this could have been the problem but even if I dont put in the bundle I get the same error, so it must be from something else.

Activity side inside a button on click:

```
MyCustomDialog myCustomDialog = MmyCustomDialog.newInstance(lat, lon, listener);
myCustomDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Comment: It looks like is trying to save something in the bundle to restart the activity later. Does it crash as well when you change the orientation while the dialog is open?

Comment: yes it does crash as well

Answer (score 1):

I see this line in your code:

```
listener = (MyListener) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_LISTENER);
```

If I guess correctly, `MyListener` is implemented either by an inner class of your Activity or by the Activity itself. Either way, MyListener holds a reference to the Activity. Please note that if your are creating an anonymous inner class, that is:

```
MyListener listener = new MyListener() { ... }
```

it still holds a reference to your Activity.

When the Fragment needs to be destroyed, the arguments Bundle is stored in the fragment state Parcel. Android tries to serialize MyListener, however Activity is not Serializable and it fails.

The usual pattern is to declare your listener interface in your Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    public interface Callbacks {
        void doSomething();
    }
    ...
```

Then an Activity that hosts the Fragment implements this interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.Callbacks {
    ...
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // do your stuff
    }
    ...
```

In `onAttach` of your Fragment you cast the Fragment's host to your Callbacks and set the field.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if (getHost() instanceof Callbacks) {
        mCallbacks = (Callbacks) getHost();
    } else {
        throw new AssertionError("Host does not implement Callbacks!");
    }
}
```

PS In the documentation you may see a version of `onAttach` method taking an `Activity`. The version above is deprecated from API 23. Until then, Fragments could be hosted only by Activities. Now, Fragments can be hosted by arbitrary objects and operate in any `Context`. That being said, you probably will host your Fragments inside Activities anyway, and your context and host will be the same.

Comment: "If I guess correctly, MyListener is an inner class of your Activity"
No it is not not. it is a separate interface in a new file. At first it was inside the MyCustomDialog which I thought was the problem. But problem still here after I moved it to a new file

I have wrote in the question that even without MyListener it crash as well

Comment: Sorry, wrong wording. What I meant is that an inner class of your Activity implements your interface or your Activity implements your interface. I updated the answer to clarify that.

Comment: But where do you see that I'm using fragment ? I'm talking about a DialogFragment here.

Comment: What helped and fixed the problemis is that instead of putSerializable(the_listener), I have set a "setter" in the dialog fragment. This worked and im not getting the serialization problem when minimzing with dialog open

Answer (score 0):

try using this method

```
dismissAllowingStateLoss();
```

instead of

```
dismiss();
```